# Cannot resolve column name when pivoting in Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

Here's my dataset

`reloadmonthly`

```
DataFrame[year: string, month: string, msisdn: string, reload_min: double, reload_max: double, reload_avg: double, reload_sum: double, rembal_min: string, rembal_max: string, rembal_avg: double, rembal_sum: double, period: string, application_type: string, periodloan: string, ix: string, last_x_month: double]
```

`reloadmonthly.show(2)`

```
+----+-----+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+----------------+----------+---+------------+
|year|month|       msisdn|reload_min|reload_max|reload_avg|reload_sum|rembal_min|rembal_max|rembal_avg|rembal_sum|period|application_type|periodloan| ix|last_x_month|
+----+-----+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+----------------+----------+---+------------+
|2019|   10| 628176789488|    5000.0|    5000.0|    5000.0|    5000.0|    5189.0|    5189.0|    5189.0|    5189.0|201910|              10|    202001|  1|         1.0|
|2019|   10|6281802031321|   25000.0|   25000.0|   25000.0|   25000.0|   25633.0|   25633.0|   25633.0|   25633.0|201910|             100|    202001|  1|         2.0|
+----+-----+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+----------------+----------+---+------------+
only showing top 2 rows
```

here's my code

```
reloadid = reloadmonthly.dropDuplicates(["msisdn"])
reloadid = reloadid.join(

    packetmonthly.withColumn("p", F.expr("concat('reload_sum_l', last_x_month)"))
    .groupBy("msisdn")
    .pivot("p")
    .sum("reload_sum"),

    on=["msisdn"],
    how="left_outer",
)
```

here's the error message

```
AnalysisException: 'Cannot resolve column name "reload_sum" among (year, month, msisdn, packet_min, packet_max, packet_avg, packet_sum, period, application_type, periodloan, ix, last_x_month, p);'
```

Comment: @darkman it is a string

Comment: It is like add_prefix in pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the `pivot` before (within) the `join`. Therefore, you are trying to pivot `packetmonthly` which, apparently, does not contain any column `reload_sum` (this column appear in `reloadmonthly`). I edited your code to enlight the part where you do the pivot within the join.

Maybe, you juste need to do the join before the pivot - I cannot really test because you did not give the definition of `packetmonthly` but the code should look like this :

```py
reloadid = (
    reloadid.join(
        packetmonthly,
        on=["msisdn"],
        how="left_outer",
    )
    .withColumn("p", F.expr("concat('reload_sum_l', last_x_month)"))
    .groupBy("msisdn")
    .pivot("p")
    .sum("reload_sum")
)
```

Comment: I also just realize my mistake few minutes before you answer this question

Comment: I am pretty sure it all can be done in single groupby instead of groubpy + join + pivot.

Comment: @darkman It is just a join + pivot (the group by is part of the pivot syntax).

Comment: we dont know the size of the real data so we can not say it is just a join + pivot + groupby. it can be improved with use of dataset api.

Answer (score -1):

```
package somePackage.notepad

import somePackage.SparkSessionTestWrapper
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, expr}

class NotepadSpec extends AnyFunSuite with SparkSessionTestWrapper with Matchers  {

  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  import spark.implicits._

  test ("Notepad test") {
    val inputData: Seq[NotepadInput] = Seq(
      NotepadInput(
        year = "2019",
        month =  "10",
        msisdn = "628176789488",
        reload_min = 5000.0,
        reload_max = 5000.0,
        reload_avg = 5000.0,
        reload_sum = 5000.0,
        rembal_min = "5189.0",
        rembal_max = "5189.0",
        rembal_avg = 5189.0,
        rembal_sum = 5189.0,
        period = "201910",
        application_type = "10",
        periodloan = "202001",
        ix = "1",
        last_x_month = 1.0,
      ),
      NotepadInput(
        year = "2019",
        month =  "10",
        msisdn = "6281802031321",
        reload_min = 25000.0,
        reload_max = 25000.0,
        reload_avg = 25000.0,
        reload_sum = 25000.0,
        rembal_min = "25633.0",
        rembal_max = "25633.0",
        rembal_avg = 25633.0,
        rembal_sum = 25633.0,
        period = "201910",
        application_type = "10",
        periodloan = "202001",
        ix = "1",
        last_x_month = 2.0,
      )
    )

    val df: DataFrame = inputData.toDF.dropDuplicates("msisdn")

    val pivotedDf: DataFrame =
      df
        .withColumn("p", expr("concat('reload_sum', last_x_month)"))
        .groupBy("msisdn")
        .pivot("p")
        .sum("reload_sum")

    val outDf: DataFrame = df
      .join(pivotedDf, Seq("msisdn"), "left_outer")

    println(outDf.show(false))
  }

}


+-------------+----+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+----------------+----------+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
|msisdn       |year|month|reload_min|reload_max|reload_avg|reload_sum|rembal_min|rembal_max|rembal_avg|rembal_sum|period|application_type|periodloan|ix |last_x_month|reload_sum1.0|reload_sum2.0|
+-------------+----+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+----------------+----------+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
|6281802031321|2019|10   |25000.0   |25000.0   |25000.0   |25000.0   |25633.0   |25633.0   |25633.0   |25633.0   |201910|10              |202001    |1  |2.0         |null         |25000.0      |
|628176789488 |2019|10   |5000.0    |5000.0    |5000.0    |5000.0    |5189.0    |5189.0    |5189.0    |5189.0    |201910|10              |202001    |1  |1.0         |5000.0       |null         |
+-------------+----+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+----------------+----------+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: I do not understand how you came to this solution. `packetmonthly` is not even defined in the question ... And it is Scala

Comment: F.expr suggests it is Pyspark and Pyspark is just an API to Spark which is written in Scala hence my response in Scala. Do you understand now?

Comment: it does not matter packetmonthly is not defined here. what's metter is the approach with the example and join flow to get right output. you can use any name you want as long as you use right schema.

Comment: I do not understand why you are giving me minus purely because of your lack of knowledge not knowing what's Pyspark relation to Scala.

Comment: There's a whole dataframe missing in his question ... No schema, no sample data. But apparently, you managed to understand how it's built. I've no idea how you did that.

Comment: we know packetmonthly has at least three columns: msisdn, reload_sum_l and last_x_month columns. we know as well reload_sum_l could be reload_sum renamed to reload_sum_l suggesting l means left but we are not sure about it. so we can use any dataframe with at least three columns msisdn, reload_sum, last_x_month to generate test case to highlight the final solution which shall help question author to solve his problem.

Comment: yes, there is no schema but somehow you deducted reload_sum_l is a string mate. so, once you say there is no schema and the other time you deduct the schema for specific column without schema being defined. how is it possible?

Comment: `reload_sum_l` is not part of `packetmonthly`. when reading `"concat('reload_sum_l', last_x_month)"`, you see that `reload_sum_l` is a simple string, not a column. He's doing a concat beetween a string and the `last_x_month` column. But you can assume anything you want, and anwser whatever seems right ...

Comment: i would prefer to see withColumn("p", concat(lit("reload_sum_l"), col("last_x_month")) instead of using expr and prefixing string type column with string like in the question to avoid confusion.